# Create angular project builder with C#

Tags: c#, angular, winforms

I ve been interested in how to speed up the process of creating angular project and installing all things u need in quicker manner than the normal one.
Since angular allows you to create projects and set some options through calls in cmd, i wanted to make C# .net app that will help me in building projects and following what have i created so far.
So i was making the app and the thing i am stuck at is how to call the function for creating the project.
Code for doing that

```
using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.location;
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
                    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;
                    process.Start();
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    process.WaitForInputIdle(10000);
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd "+Properties.Settings.Default.location );
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ng new "+projectName);
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(AngularRouting);
                    //process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
```

Properties.settings.default.location - location where i want to create it example:"C:/angularprojects"

ProcessOutputDataHandler - just storing response in string so i can read what happened and same goes for Error. Error is empty and the other one just contains string of location where i navigated to.

But it does not trigger the making of angular project on the secound written line. 
My question is mostly, was anyone trying this or did it so i can look what i did wrong and how to continue the op of creating a project since angular is sending questions through process of making like "Do you want angular routing" and a choice for css?

Comment: Wouldn't a shell script (or batch file / ps script for windows) be more convenient?

Comment: It can do the job, but thing is i want to create some kind of interface with it. Program i am making is more for personal project management with the capability to open the project through it and create one.